# How do i know if a mouse click is done on a custom component in a panel?

Tags: java, swing, click, mouseevent

I have a JPanel and some custom components in it. There are lots of such panels in the Frame. I need to know if a mouse click is on a custom component(which take for example is a JLabel).....
I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
public object getxxx(MouseEvent pEvent)
        {                                
       Point localPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(pEvent.getComponent(), pEvent.getPoint(), aPanel  );
       if (SwingUtilities.getLocalBounds(aPanel).contains(localPoint)) // This is where im facing problem, its always false in never goes in…
          {
           ///if clicked on the aPanel then do something                                            
          }
        }
```

The if condition is always false, even if i click on the desired panel

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific and provide a *working code example*. What are those custom components? Do you have to catch only clicks on them or also on the panel they are in (if it's partially exposed)?

Comment: *"I need to know if a mouse click is on a custom component"*  ..why?  What (that's different) happens when it is?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Like maybe printing out `SwingUtilities.getLocalBounds(aPanel)` and printing out `localPoint`

Comment: @user1803551,@Andrew Thompson: The final aim was that if the mouse click is on a custom component [& its a right click], i should show a context menu. I already have a mouselistener that is delegating the task of identifying which custom component is clicked..
For a custom component, imagine that i have my own class that extends a Jlabel and has some additional properties, that i added which is not related to UI..

Comment: @peeskilet: ya i tried debugging, localpoint is giving some coordinates, and getLocalBounds(panel) is giving a rec  tangle with the expected height and width.!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the MouseListener to your panel. Then you can use the `findComponentAt(...)` method of the `Container` class to return the component that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you already have and what you have left to do, but this seems to answer your needs:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    MyFrame() {

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("111");
        l1.setName("111");
        l1.setOpaque(true);
        l1.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("222");
        l2.setName("222");
        l2.setOpaque(true);
        l2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("333");
        l3.setName("333");
        l3.setOpaque(true);
        l3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        panel.add(l1);
        panel.add(l2);
        panel.add(l3);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
        panel.setName("panel");

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) { // BUTTON3 = right button
                Component c = panel.getComponentAt(e.getPoint()); // compare with panel.findComponentAt
                System.out.println("Open context menu for " + c.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- I created 3 `JLabel`s, gave them background colors to visualize the component's area on screen and names for identification. You will use your own components here instead.
- The `JPanel` containing the labels registers the `MouseListener`, which checks for a right-click. If it is, it finds the component inside the panel on which the event was generated<sup>1</sup>. You can then open your context menu there.

<sup>1</sup> Initially I had my way of getting the component at the event location, but the [answer by camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26345686/1803551) proved to be shorter. (+1)

Comment: Well this is something similar to what i needed...Thankx!

Comment: @gkurian If this answer solves your problem please consider accepting it (green checkmark). You can also upvote useful answers. If you need something added to this answer to make it the solution you need add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MouseListener` interface. See this [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Try adding a Mouse Listener to your custom component.

This code snippet could help you:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {     
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // **your code here**

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a link-only answer. You should give some more details if you don't want your answer to be flagged as low-quality.

Comment: I do have a mouse listener which calls the above code with the mouse event being passed down....
But that was not the intent, the problem was in finding if the click is inside a particular JPanel or not!!

Comment: so you need the source on which the mouse click event initially occured? you could use event.getSource() in that case

Comment: @gkurian I wouldn't go for this approach so fast. `MouseAdapter` is usually a better option and you might end up with a lot of extra code if you need to do this for each component individually.

Comment: MouseAdapter is probably the better choice because you don't need to implement every single method of the interface. I updated the code snippet